# Parsing data to ng-model not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to parse data to ng-model, but I'm getting an error.

html:

```
<div class="process-checkbox-holder" ng-repeat="time in data">
            <div class="checkbox-title">{{ time.id }}</div>
            <div class="process-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="{{ time.model}}" value="None" id="process-checkbox" name="check">
                <label for="process-checkbox"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

data:

```
$scope.data = [
            {"id":"00", "model": "user.hourzero"},
            {"id":"01", "model": "user.hourone"},
            {"id":"03", "model": "user.hourtwo"},
            {"id":"04","model": "user.hourthree"},
            {"id":"05", "model": "user.hourfour"},
            {"id":"06", "model": "user.hourfive"},
            {"id":"07", "model": "user.hoursix"},
            {"id":"08", "model": "user.hourseven"},
            {"id":"09", "model": "user.houreight"},
            {"id":"10", "model": "user.hournine"},
            {"id":"11", "model": "user.hourten"},
            {"id":"12", "model": "user.houreleven"},
            {"id":"13", "model": "user.hourthirteen"},
            {"id":"14", "model": "user.hourfourteen"},
            {"id":"15", "model": "user.hourfifteen"},
            {"id":"16", "model": "user.hoursixteen"},
            {"id":"17", "model": "user.hourseventeen"},
            {"id":"18", "model": "user.houreighteen"},
            {"id":"19", "model": "user.hournineteen"},
            {"id":"20", "model": "user.hourtwenty"},
            {"id":"21", "model": "user.hourtwentyone"},
            {"id":"22", "model": "user.hourtwentytwo"},
            {"id":"23", "model": "user.hourtwentythree"}

        ];
```

I'm getting this error:

```
 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'time.model' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 5 of the expression [{{  time.model}}] starting at [time.model}}].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$parse/syntax?p0=time.model&p1=is%20unex…cting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=5&p3=%7B%7B%20%20time.model%7D%7D&p4=time.model%7D%7D
    at angular.js:78
    at Parser.throwError (angular.js:10266)
    at Parser.consume (angular.js:10303)
    at Parser.object (angular.js:10616)
    at Parser.primary (angular.js:10234)
    at Parser.unary (angular.js:10492)
    at Parser.multiplicative (angular.js:10475)
    at Parser.additive (angular.js:10466)
    at Parser.relational (angular.js:10457)
    at Parser.equality (angular.js:10448)
```

Can anyone help me what I'm doing wrong here? Is it not possible to parse data into ng-model? Many thanks

[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/PB0anvLcdTn14lJXX9B3?p=preview)

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: you can't pass object reference in strings like that. ng-model needs to be able to resolve as a scope object. You will need to create directive that parses those model strings into template

Comment: I have now added PLNKR

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not sure how to implement the directives into ng-model..can you please help me in my PLNKR?

Comment: As presented you would have to have a directive run $scope.$eval on every single time.model object in this array, and assign ng-model to that value. Would suggest you simplify your data model more before you assign it to scope, rather than something this complex.

Comment: start by explaining what you are trying to do. I see you want dynamic checkboxes but beyond that what is objective?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to have dynamic checkboxes, so instead of creating/repeating 24 html div elements on the page, I just want to create one div as above and loop it through...so that it save me of 24 divs creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach to using directive to parse your model strings by compiling the template with `$compile`

HTML

```
<div class="process-checkbox-holder" ng-repeat="time in data">
    <span class="checkbox-title">{{ time.id }}</span>
    <check-box model="time.model" user='user'></check-box>
  </div>
```

JS

```
app.directive('checkBox', function($compile){
    return {           
        restrict:'E',       
        scope:{model : '=', user:'='},
        link:function(scope,elem,attrs){             
           var template ='<input  type="checkbox" ng-model="'+scope.model+'">';
           elem.replaceWith($compile(template)(scope));
       }
    }
});
```

This requires using an isolated scope so you must declare the `user` in controller for this to work. This may not be the best approach if you will be needing to add validation as well but for now it covers what was shown.

I tried to keep it as simple as possible for now.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y9bg197t9oVdpTaX7sWS?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Also don't use "{{ }}" syntax in ng- directives.